# Play-slick connection error to mysql db

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I try to connect to my local mysql database, but i get a "db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1000ms." error. I checked the documentations, but every setting seems to be OK. The max connection setting of the db is also set to a right amount.

Versions:
Play: 2.6.15, Scala: 2.12.2

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.11"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.1"
```

application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "user"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = "password"
```

db call

```
val db = databaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db
try {
  Await.result(db.run(dbio.transactionally), timeout)
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage)
}
```

Comment: I don't see an error with your configuration... the database is up and running, right? And the JDBC URL is correct? Maybe double-check http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef@forConfig(String,Config,Driver,ClassLoader):Database

Comment: It's working now, i use the Database.forConfig() instead of the DatabaseConfigProvider to get the db. I don't know the reason behind it. If someone can give me an explanation then i'll close the question.